# Can't get the data from the stream

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, stream, minio

I have some code that in which I build a minIO client and the I try to access an object through the getObject method and the perform other tasks. The thing is I can't get the data from the stream. I have tried to with Buffer.from and push the data in the buff array. No result. Any thoughts??? Thank you!

The code is below:

```
var Minio = require('minio')
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;

async function  call(){
    var minioClient = new Minio.Client({
        endPoint: 'localhost',
        port: 9000,
        useSSL: false,
        accessKey: 'admin',
        secretKey: 'password'
    });

    minioClient.listBuckets(function (err, buckets) {
        if (err)
            return console.log(err);
        console.log('buckets :', buckets);
    });

    var buff = [];
    var size = 0;
    await minioClient.getObject("test2", "test.jpg").then( function(dataStream) {           
        dataStream.on('data', async function(chunk) {
          buff.push(chunk)
          size += chunk.length
        })
        dataStream.on('end', function() {
          console.log('End. Total size = ' + size)
          console.log("End Buffer : " + buff)
        })
        dataStream.on('error', function(err) {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }).catch((err)=>console.log(err));      
    
    console.log("Buffer = " + buff);
    return buff;
}


var data = call();
console.log("Data: " + data);
```

the reponse is below:

```
Data: [object Promise]
buckets : [
  { name: 'test1', creationDate: 2021-08-25T18:36:40.544Z },
  { name: 'test2', creationDate: 2021-08-25T19:42:47.558Z }
]
End. Total size = 3844
End Buffer: ����►JFIF☺☺☺����☺vPhotoshop 3.08BIM♦♦☺N∟☻☻☻∟☻¶ww.public-domain-image.com∟☻t,Murphy Karen, U.S. Fish and Wildlife Service∟☻zww.public-domain-im
age.com∟☻(�Please consider to donate and to link back to http://www..public-domain-image.com also give credit for this and any other pictures you used.∟☻A
"http://www.public-domain-image.com∟☻18991230∟☻<♂000000+01008BIM♦♂��C♥☻☻♥☻☻♥♥♥♥♦♥♥♦♣♣♦♦♣
♀
♀♀♂
¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶����♥☺"☻◄☺♥◄☺��▼☺♣☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☻♥♦♣♠
♂���►☻☺♥♥☻♦♥♣♣♦♦☺}☺☻♥♦◄♣↕!1A♠‼Qa"q¶2��#B��§R��$3br�
▬↨↑↓→%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������▼☺♥☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☻♥♦♣♠
♂���◄☻☺☻♦♦♥♦♣♦♦☺☻w☺☻♥◄♦♣!1♠↕AQaq‼"2¶B����       #3R�§br�
▬$4�%�↨↑↓→&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������♀♥☺☻◄♥◄?���M∟q�VŞ�↨▼-hY��oO
Ҵ���0�§̏a2���↑`/?J�ob#lm▼�^����▲♣Zk}�☼CBв�ه♀
♀{��֡r�F>��→|����T�↔���-��RXm���6zRǤ^2)►�3�"�[M?ΙC(�z�d�X���c∟V�:∟�����6gA��8��o��"y⌂�8<
y�q�x�c�=☼j��↔M▼♫�>L`�zUۭ♠%�8DeR0♫}k☼D�y/e�k�펽8�(#�#��%�m��r驔w:�☼٫FP(�ۊ��4peO�~U�౟)Xd→�
☺��G�r�j��4§�►�~n��t��3*�9◄�d:y���zԏK'♀=3�U�q\
��i→�?J�9O;�∟�ٔ�¶�m��~u�Gf:c"��¿�i�→\Æ�����↔=�a��z��:n1�Vc���L��Br�dZ��L↑���w◄�;V�Yv�2K'�]�!O§�W!���    |��§��_K,�B=��$��~N����U�>����n�§�↑&a)3'K�o8<h��0
����G�7↨♥.rߕI���R�<v���K[��iJ�#v��~�▬`�¨�B���U��U=M[x�����X�♠�z�+��ע��⌂F��Gj���a�1�>ұ4�6�↑�nF��♀◄\�M;�IE=ϋ���"�▼ː8����J͹@�kҌ�3�D♂▲��L��o�M�Q��z|ڛ'tX��☼ީ�◄
�♣W↕mۃ��ٮq�↔h��(�pĜ��!�n�U♂����¶���Q�+�;∟���Eh����q�rI��5NI<�·▲�j�Bw�=�G+lDS���aj��c▲��]<(#ҹ�{���mX�.��\�Vu�tGc�8N���7��☼5��� �����(∟�*3����Y�,Y�9�◄x
�ڹ(n�j��▼'�§�ܩ7���x♫?:��`pX‼^/�
�T����?)������Sqc�♂��3Ϧ=k�Q�s�▬2���*�▬▼�Y�Ѝ‼�=s^/�
�P�↓�.↑��⌂�[o☺�sD#o►�§▲���G,{��=^mj�,��4♥��☻�7�l$�↨��♫?�☼�!��36���_�'��∟��A⌂g��#�↨JO�☼�↔�5����;��\B�(�♦���3��z��q�%������
ci���y, ��§.��Kx→�M�X�y�3F�☼8�G��x���:Yۻ_�#�ƕr��I�YTM�߰#�▼Ҳӫ4�>=☼����;������T�<���������O�Jl:��3־t�⌂d▼☼I!W�/�G'��
�t�؏�ן�uV�����♣X���>↑�pm���~hʓ�§�=q����&��`o��[VmgWq�]W���]f��♦��^�t���X♫�+���G����EN��♂�F1��ULd▼ҩ��2~���~�GN9�n�>C��H��#�cm�u�+1f�9����4���Ea֟�g§��▲�ȩ���
�
t�0�m�W?�s���ţ�4�Y�#�N~���▼Xܫ�↑��`��׍�ѕmȥJ������1#?19♦(������↓4���<��♥7J<�܌�∟��:zn8?ʻ☼;�=�ƭ��CScb2I���u2����9"=¶�c��Wx8�29§q��}☼���C����
QD��⌂.jm�^j����g>�♦�:
��♂ o��B��4�$\��ٹ8�9Q�E�{a!�Q�Z�l�/|TV�nS�sV�✔!s�����`�E�/O��;q��Mi��1�}�ǡ�M▬�♥☻I�↕���5�[�▲B�,:m/�����=*qF֙n#���↔8?S]%�1�! ���
�↑���#��V♂�1�ܲ�V�2D��I►���r�3�ֹӻ:,|��↔�+�u`ib�]�,�I��X��m ����W▬�I>�♫���5w����∟��$#�y�O��V`�↨ܟ����!fY1��↔vը��♫��h�%HԊm�u��]�+Hw∟���L�?J�↨↕6�߇?�7�▼0���Lw5▬
�qA.E֝���Gc��D�▲☺+�ʫ_�z���☼���ݕ�}*���9→��§A!�♥�♥?έ[�    92↨���
�s�WIiek$�2∟Ɩhś∟�§H'����E�m↨m�����;�w��b����⌂♥|♥�⌂��t▬q�→eǊ↓ss;�#ʌG1��g↑↔k�T����/�5���u=8˗���ac:�u���#j�G�C��k��i�♥�♀[���}��?�}�&�k7��h_���U;�
�ׇ3ivr���S�+?�4�4���∟↨%[���F�♣�F♥1s�v����ކ±�↑-�Ҵ�,�\▲��R<yH݉��.s�槎c#r�O�d�6��%�:U�9�p3�8§fw4�઀ͳ�ˌ�b̽�>�C�c�F;�O;z��n~�h♫cR6��_�Ҭ�Ŕ.q�:VLst���Y�G�ڋ�r���54
sw^���16�►☼�J_�,��♂.s�♫*�K�6waq���M��.t����,↨AYC��H##�‼��o���$a��t�*��↓↑�M�⌂�A�֨Jz�����
↕�a�]E��ۇux�*2Us�^}I4�g�Nw��փ�Qx�O��P�R�c�<�)?���Ew�?�֡j���{[����v����→��H�W���x�nLHǟ�♥���K���%�>P˟�-�z�:�☻�֚z�k���
```

Comment: Where is `<ref *2> IncomingMessage { a lot of data }` coming from? And why can't you get data from it?

Comment: It's comming from the if (err) { return console.log(err) }

Comment: I corrected the code. I get the above message but i want the information to come to the response of call function. not to be printed only in the dataStream.on('end', function() {
          console.log('End. Total size = ' + size)
          console.log("Buffer : " + buff)
          return  buff;
        }) response handler.

Comment: Do you want the information in `console.log("Buffer = " + buff);` or outside`console.log("Data: " + data);` (which is a Promise) ?

Comment: I want the information at the var data. The second to last line. And from then on to perform other task. funny thing i think with python it's a little easier without all the promises and stuff... Just for the reference.

Comment: If I have the information after the `console.log("Buffer = " + buff);` it helps too.

Answer (score 2):

##### A running example. to get the the data as you need it.

```js
var minioClient = new Minio.Client({
  endPoint: 'play.min.io',
  port: 9000,
  useSSL: true,
  accessKey: 'Q3AM3UQ867SPQQA43P2F',
  secretKey: 'zuf+tfteSlswRu7BJ86wekitnifILbZam1KYY3TG'
})
async function call() {

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var buff = [];
    var size = 0;
    minioClient.getObject("sph-my-bucket", "test-replication.txt").then(function(dataStream) {
      dataStream.on('data', async function(chunk) {
        buff.push(chunk)
        size += chunk.length
      })
      dataStream.on('end', function() {
        console.log('End. Total size = ' + size)
        // console.log("End Buffer : " + buff)

        resolve(buff)
      })
      dataStream.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err)
        reject(err)
      })
    }).catch(reject);

  })

  return promise

}


async function getData() {

  const data = await call()

  console.log(data.toString())
}

getData()
```

Answer (score 0):

Async/await is basically a sintax sugar for Promises. But you have to keep in mind that an `async`function [always returns a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value), even if you explicitly don't wrap its `return` in one.

With this said, as we know, if we want to retrieve the information, just call `Promise.then()` and assign the result to your global variable. Note: `setTimeout` just adds a delay to until the Promise fullfill.

```js
async function getAsync() {
    var response = await fetch('https://placekitten.com/500/500');
    var data = await response.text();
    return data;
}

var myData;
getAsync().then(data => myData = data);

setTimeout(() => console.log(myData), 3e3)
```